# updated according to the time zone

Tags: mysql

I have the program below whose goal is to update col2 every day at 23h59min59s. the problem is that we have accounts all over Africa and europe. I would like the program to run every day at 23:59:59 depending on the timezone of each account. For example, if the account is in France, the DBMS should automatically change the value of col2. if the account is in cameroon and it is 23h, col2 must be updated.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `updateColumn`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `updateColumn`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-04-15 23:59:59' // I Want 23h59min59s du timezone
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
  update ma_table set col2=col1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

the column is actually updated but the update dates aren't good.

Comment: Define "dates aren't good".

Comment: @ceejayoz Bad experiences on Tinder…?

Comment: @deceze `DELETE FROM organs WHERE type='kidney' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @ceejayoz Better make sure you only trigger that one once.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that You need to add information about record timezone in the row (ACCOUNT). I.e. column GMT_TIMEZONE_INFO. Then in this event update on **each hour** where Server time + GMT_TIMEZONE_INFO is midnight(or whatever time you want).